# SourceTree でブランチ同士を比較する方法

Tags: sourcetree

2017年4月末ごろにSourceTreeのデザインが新しくなりましたが、
ブランチとブランチのソースを比較する方法が分かりません。
教えて頂けますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Ver2.0.20.1での操作方法です。画面左側にブランチの一覧が表示されているかと思うので
比較対象のブランチを右クリック→「**現在の内容とDiffを表示**」を実行してみて下さい。